# How to draw a 1px line between flex boxes

Tags: css

I would like to use CSS to draw 1px black lines between "cards" in a matrix in a responsive design:

- Cards are all in a container
- All cards have the same size
- 3 cards per row for big screens
- 2 cards per row for small screens
- Total of 6 cards (i.e.: the container is always filled)
- Separation line is black with 1px width

So for big screens:

[image]

And for small screens:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this with only CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS grid and without media query:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  background: black;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,minmax(clamp(33%,300px,45%),1fr));
  gap: 1px;
  grid-auto-rows:200px;
}
.card {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

more fancy without any style applied to card (I don't really advice)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,minmax(clamp(33%,300px,45%),1fr));
  gap: 1px;
  grid-auto-rows:200px;
  border-right:1px solid yellow;
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 0 calc(100% - 1px),black 0)
      0 0/clamp(33%,365px,45%) 100% round border-box,
    repeating-linear-gradient(transparent 0 200px,black 0 201px)
    yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Another one:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,minmax(clamp(33%,300px,45%),1fr));
  gap: 1px;
  grid-auto-rows:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.card {
  background: yellow;
  outline:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing another solution! ^^ It seems yours has the same issue as mine. when the `.container` div is inside another `.main` div, and we set `.main { margin: 50.5px; }`, then when resizing with Chrome, sometimes a 1px line appears at the right. Does not happen with Firefox. Any idea? If it is not trivial, I'll just ask another question. :-)

Comment: @Peque a small quirck around background and sub pixel rendring. I am adding another solution that should not produce this ;)

Comment: @Peque check the update and see if the same issue occur or not

Comment: Definitely a solution it would have not thought about! xD. The issue is not gone, but mitigated. Instead of seeing a black line at the right, it is now gray... with varying level of gray... :-D

Comment: @Peque added a third one, maybe better ;)

Comment: Nah, it also occurs... :-) I guess it is hard to fight against these things, specially when behavior is different with different browsers (as I mentioned with Firefox I can't see the issue). Thanks anyways! ^^

Comment: PS: updated my own answer with the `.main` div in case you are curious and want to reproduce it. But maybe since it is browser-related you can't. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use a flex container with a black background and 1px gap between cards.

Not sure it is the best way to do it, but it seems to work as expected as long as the container is fully filled with cards:

```css
.main {
  margin: 50.5px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: black;
  gap: 1px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.card {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 30%;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    flex: 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only issue with this solution is that it may fail to render as expected depending on the browser you are using. I tried with Firefox and it seems to work just fine, but with Chrome, you may see a 1px black line at the right depending on the width of your window (i.e.: try to slowly resize the window and you may see it appear and disappear):

[image]

### Update

In order to avoid this issue, you can use:

```css
background: 
  linear-gradient(black 0 0) center/calc(100% - 1px) 100% no-repeat;
```

As suggested by [@temani-afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333) in their [more complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66601377/3577054).